# Umbraco/Azure Blob List Caching

Tags: azure, caching, azure-blob-storage, umbraco7

Using a Partial View in an Umbraco V7.3.0 site to connect to and list out an Azure Blob Storage Container. The page displays the Container in a traditional folder/file tree. The problem I have is that reloading the page appends another copy of the tree to the bottom of the first, ad infinitum.  I don't know where the caching is happening, Umbraco, Web Server or Azure? Is this behaviour to be expected, is there a way to control it? Any advice on how to work out where it's caching would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bug in the logic whereby you are adding the retrieved data (the directory listing) to the existing data rather than first reinitializing the existing data - is that possible?

Comment: I don't *think* so as all the objects are new'd or initialised to empty:

 IEnumerable<CloudBlobContainer> containerList = client.ListContainers(rootContainer);
 HtmlString listing = null;
 foreach(var container in containerList) {
  listing = getContainerDirectories(container.ListBlobs());
 
  @Html.Raw(listing);
 
  }

And (see next comment)......

Comment: .... (from  last comment).....

 public static HtmlString getContainerDirectories(IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobList) {

     var sb = new StringBuilder("");
     var finalOutput = new TagBuilder("div");

     sb.AppendLine(getDirectoriesAndContents(blobList,0).ToString());

     finalOutput.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();

     return new HtmlString(finalOutput.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
 }

Comment: Adding a count variable shows me that the list of blobs being pulled from Azure is the same on each page load. However the displayed count continues to rise unless the project is rebuilt (app restart I guess). So have tried decorating the helper function that does the blobList interrogation and output string manipulation with outputcache but makes no difference. This assumes the issue is MVC though not sure if it's overridden by Umbraco itself.